# Автоматический деплой с bitbucket на сервер

Tags: git, bitbucket, развертывание

Каким образом лучше реализовать автоматический деплой проекта с *bitbucket*?
Есть ветка *master*. Нужно при изменении этой ветки автоматически выгружать код на сервер.

Answer (score 2):

Если не хочется сильно заморачиваться, то, например, [DeployHQ](https://www.deployhq.com/). Если хочется сделать самостоятельно и бесплатно, то настройте себе [вебхуки в BitBucket](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/manage-webhooks-735643732.html), благо туториалов тьма. Выбирайте нужный себе язык и гуглите. [Вот PHP](http://jonathannicol.com/blog/2013/11/19/automated-git-deployments-from-bitbucket/), например.